# Create data for ListStreamPlot in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Good evening everyone!! I have a problem when importing files in a specific format in Mathematica. In my research, I generate files by Fortran's `write (10) x, y, Vx, Vy` which are positions and values ​​of the components of vector fields. I need to plot this data in ListStreamPlots but I don't know how to produce the table correctly. `data = Import [" / home / davib / Documents / teste.dat "," Table "];`

An example of an output file (only for testing):

```
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
  0.10000000000000001        0.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000002E-002   1.0000000000000002E-002
  0.20000000000000001        0.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000008E-002   4.0000000000000008E-002
  0.30000000000000004        0.0000000000000000        9.0000000000000024E-002   9.0000000000000024E-002
  0.40000000000000002        0.0000000000000000       0.16000000000000003       0.16000000000000003     
  0.50000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       0.25000000000000000       0.25000000000000000     
  0.60000000000000009        0.0000000000000000       0.36000000000000010       0.36000000000000010     
  0.70000000000000007        0.0000000000000000       0.49000000000000010       0.49000000000000010     
  0.80000000000000004        0.0000000000000000       0.64000000000000012       0.64000000000000012     
  0.90000000000000002        0.0000000000000000       0.81000000000000005       0.81000000000000005     
   1.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000     
   1.1000000000000001        0.0000000000000000        1.2100000000000002        1.2100000000000002     
   1.2000000000000002        0.0000000000000000        1.4400000000000004        1.4400000000000004     
   1.3000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        1.6900000000000002        1.6900000000000002     
   1.4000000000000001        0.0000000000000000        1.9600000000000004        1.9600000000000004     
   1.5000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        2.2500000000000000        2.2500000000000000     
   1.6000000000000001        0.0000000000000000        2.5600000000000005        2.5600000000000005
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What kind of problem do you have? Any error message?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the documentation `ListStreamPlot` takes data of the form

`{ { { x, y }, { vx, vy } } ,...}`

while your import produces

`{ { { x, y , vx, vy } } ,...}`

This is easily solved by

```js
newdata = Partition[ #, 2] &/@ data
```

Which maps ( Map[] ) your data, i.e. the blocks of 4-vectors on the `Partition`function, which splits those in half.

Comment: That's right hehehe Thank you very much !!! I am very new to Mathematica and I am still learning the language.